# Adding controls on CFrameWnd MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How can I add control(like ListCtrl and CButtons) on CFrameWnd?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be to create a [CDialogBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkcfwe6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and stick your controls on that.

Comment: Thanks. But any advice  or suggestion for CFrameWnd

Comment: CFrameWnd is exactly that, a frame. If you want controls within your frame then put them on a dialog bar as I suggested, or a view.

Answer (score 0):

CListCtrl is the same as CListView. You can also create button by calling directly button’s Create member or calling Create API passing BUTTON as the name of the class.

If you want to use many controls like in a dialog why not to use CFormView derived class as your view?